# ODR-usage behaviour rationale

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

Why passing argument by const reference **always** means the object is ODR-used? I understand, because Standard defines it this way, but why didn't it make exception at least for integral constants?

For example (my own example from the answer several hours ago):

```
struct T {
    static constexpr int i = 42;
};

void check(const int& z);

int main() {
    check(T::i); // <- 1
    check(42); // <- 2
}
```

Line `(1)` will triger an error at link time - standard considers it to be ODR-using of `T::i`, and no definition is in sight. However, standard has no problem with example `(2)`. And since `(2)` has to work, why can't `(1)` work for intgeral `constexpr`? I realize that generally you need to take an address of the object to pass it by reference, but certainly not in case of numeric literals. Why wouldn't standard craft the exception for some `constexpr` types?

Is it simply to avoid too many exceptions in the standard? But I see allowing usage as above as very beneficial! Is there anything else I fail to see?

Comment: what you have written would make more sense if you told us what `x` is and what `check` does, as you did here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37259949/3758484

Comment: Simple answer: There is no x

Comment: I wonder why people downvoted this question. I also wonder why is it 'primarily opinion based' - there is nothing opinion based, @Barry did explain it quite well.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just pass by value.

Comment: @AlanStokes, well, I thought people here understand the value of example, as opposed to real code. In real code, `check()` would be a template and passing by value would be inapproriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, standard has no problem with example (2)

Because in the case of (2), we're creating a *temporary* of type `int const&` that is bound to the prvalue `42`.

But `T::i` isn't an rvalue, it's an lvalue - so we're not going to try to create a temporary, we're going to try to bind to the actual object. But how would the compiler know that `T::i` is an lvalue  that you don't want to eventually provide a definition for, that in this case what you really mean is to construct a temporary and copy it? `constexpr` isn't part of the type, the type of `i` is simply `int const`. You'd probably have to jump through a ton of hurdles to even try to come up with a wording that would correctly exempt your `static constexpr int i` but some member `const int i`.

All to solve what problem? You could just manually perform the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion via `+T::i` and achieve the same thing. Or provide a definition for `T::i`.

The ODR rules are complicated enough - you'd need a compelling reason to drill a hole in them.

Comment: Actually, it makes sense now, when you expressed it in terms of lvalues vs rvalues. I didn't see that as the defining reason.

Comment: Cool, I now know two really obscure things you can use unary + for! (Integral promotion is the other.)

Comment: @Barry Thanks! Though I'm not sure whether to laugh or cry.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the same call occurs in two TUs. The function `check` could take the address of `z`, and the standard guarantees that it will see the same address in both calls.

How would you make that happen other than by allocating a single storage location and putting `i` there? Which is pretty much what ODR-used is saying.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. If the address is the only problem, it could be worked the same as for literals.

Comment: No, it couldn't. `check(1)` called from two different TUs is allowed to pass two different addresses; `check(T::i)` is not. And `check` can tell the difference.

Comment: We could craft an exception for `constexpr` and the address and make the same rules as for literals? I think, I find @Barry answer in terms of rvalue vs rvalue more convincing.

Comment: So you'd say that a `constexpr` variable's address can be different in different expressions? That seems fundamentally bad to me. And it would mean adding a `constexpr` could break working code.

Comment: Bad or good can be based on something. Why is it bad? I find it to be good. What is meant by 'working code'? Pre-constexpr code doesn't have constexpr, so no legacy behavior is broken. New code would be written with that in mind.

Comment: You'd have to rewrite the object model from scratch. Do you really not want to be able to add `constexpr` to existing code without checking every single usage of the variable? Some other TU might have `static_assert(&x == &x)`, or a more complex equivalent.