# I am trying to write templatized code to compare two vector but i am getting these error

Tags: c++, templates, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 5

template<typename T>
class vec {
 T*ptr;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    public:
    
    vec():size(0),capacity(BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
        ptr = new T[capacity];
    }
    vec(int size1)
    {
        capacity=size1;
        ptr = new T[capacity];
        
    }
    void push_back(T val)
    {
        if(size==capacity)
        {
            T*ptr1 = new T[capacity];
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                ptr1[i]=std::move(ptr[i]);
            }
            delete[] ptr;
            ptr = nullptr;
            capacity+=BLOCK_SIZE;
            ptr = new T[capacity];
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                ptr[i]=std::move(ptr1[i]);
            }
            delete[] ptr1;
            ptr1= nullptr;
        }
        ptr[size++]=val;
    }
    
    T& operator[] (int num)
    {
        return ptr[num];
    }
    bool operator == (vec<T> obj)
    {
    if (this->size != obj.size) {
        return false; // Different sizes, not equal
    }
    else
    return true;
    }
    template<typename U>
    friend bool operator==(const vec<U>& lhs, const vec<U>& rhs);
};

template<typename T>
bool operator==(const vec<T>& lhs, const vec<T>& rhs) {
    if (lhs.size != rhs.size) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lhs.size; ++i) {
        if (lhs.ptr[i] != rhs.ptr[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    vec<std::string> vec1;
    vec<int> vec2(10);
    vec2.push_back(100);
    vec1.push_back("abhinav");

    std::cout << vec1[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << vec2[0] << std::endl;

    if (vec1 == vec2) {
        std::cout << "Same vectors" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Different vectors" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

below is error i am getting in gcc compiler

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:86:14: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘vec >’ and ‘vec’)
   86 |     if (vec1 == vec2) {
      |         ~~~~ ^~ ~~~~
      |         |       |
      |         |       vec<int>
      |         vec<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>
main.cpp:50:10: note: candidate: ‘bool vec::operator==(vec) [with T = int]’ (reversed)
   50 |     bool operator == (vec<T> obj)
      |          ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:50:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘vec>’ to ‘vec’
   50 |     bool operator == (vec<T> obj)
      |                       ~~~~~~~^~~
```

How to modify this code so i can compare any two types of vector

Comment: Why do you have an `operator==` declared both inside the class and outside? Either can work (although outside is better) but having both makes little sense.

Comment: A side note: instead of a `#define` for your constant value, you can use a more modern `inline constexpr int BLOCK_SIZE = 5;`. See more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466591/replacing-constants-when-to-use-static-constexpr-and-inline-constexpr.

Comment: If you really want to compare different types of vector then that would be `template<typename T, typename U>
bool operator==(const vec<T>& lhs, const vec<U>& rhs)` though obviously this will still not work for `std::string` and `int` because there is no `operator==` defined for those two types. But it should work for `vec<double>` and `vec<float>` for example.

Comment: @user265906 - following the comments under my answer below, can you explain why you actually need to compare these types of different vectors ? It might be an XY problem.

Comment: `bool operator == (vec<T> obj)` -- This is broken, all due to your `vec` class violating the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  You ae passing `obj` by value, meaning a copy will be made.  Your class lacks a user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor.  '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator==` is expecting both `vec`s to be of the same type `T`.

This actually makes sense.

In this line:

```
if (vec1 == vec2) {
```

You are attempting to compare a `vec<std::string>` to a `vec<int>`.
The compiler is emitting an error because it does not comply to your `operator==` declaration.

Even if you did implement a `operator==` for such a case I don't see much point in it.
The only case in which you can consider them really equal is if they are both empty, which is something you can easily test without convoluting the semantics of `operator==`.

Having said that, if for some reason you need some special sematics like comparing a `vec<int>` to `vec<string>` after converting the `string`s to `int`s you should implement a specific overload for it.

---

Update:
As [john commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78131474/i-am-trying-to-write-templatized-code-to-compare-two-vector-but-i-am-getting-the/78131502?noredirect=1#comment137743229_78131474) one use case for supporting comparison between different `vec` types could be for comparing numeric values (e.g. `int`s and `float`s).  In this case you need to change the declaration to use 2 template parameters (like `T`, `U`):

```
template<typename T, typename U> 
bool operator==(const vec<T>& lhs, const vec<U>& rhs) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: For your answer to be more complete: If the operator == is invoked from template code, it may make sense to define it for vectors of different types.  In this situation, defining it would make sense, presumably returning false.

Comment: @wearetherobots you are right that it could be done. But as I mentioned in my answer, I don't see much use for such an implementation. The only reasonable case IMHO is for different numeric types as john commented above. Updated my answer with it.

Comment: even with `std::string` and `int` they could have a `operator==` that returns `false` when `T != U` and compares the elements otherwise

Comment: I'm not the downvoter.  But I'm guessing it's to do with the fact that the question from the op was "How to modify this code so i can compare any two types of vector?", and the answer given seemed to be: "you don't need to do that".

Comment: @wearetherobots thanks for the feedback. I focused on explaining the compiler error and questioning the motive, but I see the reason in what you wrote.